# Use gzip to uncompress svgz file: unknown suffix

Tags: terminal, compression

I tried to uncompress a `.svgz` file using gzip, but encountered `gzip: p1.svgz: unknown suffix -- ignored`.

```
$ gzip -d p1.svgz
gzip: p1.svgz: unknown suffix -- ignored
```

I added the suffix `.gz` to the `.svgz` file, and still didn't work.

```
$ gzip -d p1.svgz.gz 
gzip: p1.svgz.gz: not in gzip format
```

Here is the header of my `.svgz` file.

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 1172 1600" version="1.1" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" text-rendering="geometricPrecision" class="p1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><style type="text/css">text{white-space:pre;font-size:16px;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;fill:none;unicode-bidi:bidi-override}@font-face{font-family:"p1_g_d0_f1";src:url("data:application/font-woff;charset=utf-8;
```

`file p1.svgz` returns `p1.svgz: SVG Scalable Vector Graphics image`.

Comment: What does `file p1.svgz` give you? Also, the file already seems to be plain text so maybe it's just the suffix which is wrong?

Comment: @nohillside, it gives me `p1.svgz: SVG Scalable Vector Graphics image`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you already can read the header of the file with `head` or `cat`, the file is not compressed at all.